# cx_Freeze .py to exe file not working on other computer

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I've used cx_Freeze to convert my python file into an exe file. I also have a "setup.py" file that I've put the code for below. The exe file works perfectly on my computer but when I try it on another PC, it doesn't run. It shows the command prompt for like 2 seconds and then vanishes. I was hoping if you could help me in understanding why this issue occurs and how I can solve it?

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

setup(name = "events_application" , 
      version = "0.1" , 
      description = "" , 
      executables = [Executable("events.py")])
```

I even created a zip folder that contains the "build" folder where my application would be and sent it to my friend but it still didnt work.

Comment: Run the application in a command shell to see whether there are errors shown on the console.

Comment: okay i'll check it out

Comment: So I checked on the other PC, turns out I'm getting an error that says "Cannot connect to localhost because the machine actively refused it". How do I solve this?

Comment: What does your program do "connect to localhost"?  Is it a socket client trying to connect to a server? Or is it trying to connect to a database?  I think you need to save the host information in a configuration file instead of hard-coded in the program.

Comment: I'm just using pymysql.connect. For the host i say 'localhost' and the port is 3306.

Comment: You should use a configuration file to hold the MySQL server IP address, then load this IP address on program startup instead of hard-coded "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

I had to write this in a comment, but unfortunetly no reputation, Just use auto-py-to-exe, the best solution,See more from [here.](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)

Comment: I ran auto-py-to-exe and it works perfectly on my computer but on my friend's PC on the command prompt, it doesn't show any error. A separate window is opened saying "Failed to execute script events"

Comment: try to see other devices, because probably the problem is from your friend's pc

Comment: I've tried two other PC's and they're saying the same thing.